# Finding islands in a 2D matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, matrix-equations

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but what equation or mathematical notation would be appropriate to find the number of islands in a 2D matrix?

Let islands be defined as connected groups of orthogonally adjacent like elements.

Let finite matrix $A$ be comprised of zeroes and ones where $|A|$ is square. $A$ contains two islands, the sum of mutually exclusive unconnected subsets of $A$.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Programmatically this could be solved with an algorithm by iterating through an array until you find a 1, incrementing the number of islands, recursively searching adjacent elements while marking each element as visited until the entire island is found, and continuing to the end.

Thank you,

Comment: Since A is notated as a set, A = {0,1}.  What is an island?  What did you intend A to be?

Comment: Ah yes, changed set to multiset. An island is a group of adjoined like elements, typically in a 2D matrix.

Comment: @Pandazoic: Even as multiset it doesn't work. While a multiset can contain the same element several times, there still is no order in it, that is, $\{0,0,0,1,1\}=\{0,0,1,0,1\}=\{1,0,0,1,0\}=\ldots$.

Comment: Hm, yeah as a bag there wouldn't be such a thing as an ordered multiset, huh? Could be strange to use a one-dimensional matrix for a 2D problem, but changing this to 2D would drastically change the original intent. Thanks for the guidance on this!

Comment: Well, since the very first step I would do is a bijection of the one-dimensional index to a pair of indices for the coordinates, I don't see the fundamental difference representing it as 1D would make. After all, whatever you'd do would have to be a 2D description in disguise.

Comment: Great point! I suppose there wouldn't be a difference at all in the equation if I'm just using pairs anyways. For simplicity I'll change this to a 2D matrix.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an immutable mathematical solution", but mathematically you are talking about the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component) of an [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of a [grid graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph) (the one induced by the subset of vertices labeled 1). In image processing this is also known as [connected-component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

Comment: @Rahul: Thank you for the links, that's definitely it. By immutable I just meant to contrast this with the typical programmatic solution. An equation rather than an algorithm with mutable variables.

Comment: There is no equation for the connected components unfortunately. What would such an equation even look like?

Comment: If not an equation, there must be formal notation for this such as set theory in image processing.